# Display a list in a view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model Course, a model Component and a model Evaluation:

```
public class Course
 {
   public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Component> Components { get; set; }
   public virtual List<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Evaluation> Evaluation { get; set; }
 }

public class Component
 {
   public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
   public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
   public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
   public virtual string NameComp { get; set; }
 }

public class Evaluation
{

   public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

   public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
   public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

   public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

   public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

I need to show in a view a table with all the users, all the components created and the grade for each one.
I tried this way:

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Username
    </th>
    @foreach (var x in Model.Components)
    {
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.NameComp)
        </th>
    }
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Evaluation)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
        </td>
        @foreach (var x in Model.Components)
        {

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
            </td>
        }
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But this gives me all the components in one column, and i need one column for each component, and a grade for each one:

The code i have gives this:

```
Username - Component1Component2Component3
   Test  -              12 
   Test  -              13
   Test  -              10
(example of result with username and grades)
```

And i need:

```
Username - Component1 - Component2 - Component3
  Test   -    12      -    13      -    10 
(example of result with username and grades)
```

How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: The model looks incorrect. Ideally, evaluation should be grouped by UserId. It should be IGrouping<string, Evaluation> Evaluations or List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Evaluation>>> Evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Evaluations in Course should be:

```
public virtual IGrouping<string, Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }
```

The code should be:

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Username
    </th>
    <th>
    @foreach (var x in Model.Components)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.NameComp)
    }
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var group in Model.Evaluations)
{
<tr>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => group.Key)
    </td>
    @foreach (var item in group)
    {
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
        </td> 
    }
    <td>
    </td>
}
</tr>
```

Comment: It gives an error in the @foreach (var item in group): "foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type 'SGP.Models.Evaluation' because 'SGP.Models.Evaluation' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: The Model needs to be modified to use IGrouping.

Comment: I've done it like you said, instead of public virtual List<Evaluation> Evaluation i have public virtual IGrouping<string, Evaluation> Evaluations

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the evaluation is in reference to a course component:

```
public class Evaluation
{

    public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

    public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Here are some test values:

```
var users = new List<UserProfile>
{
    new UserProfile { UserId = 1, UserName = "Jim" },
    new UserProfile { UserId = 2, UserName = "Sam" },
};

var components = new List<Component>
{
    new Component { ComponentId = 1, NameComp = "Unit 1" },
    new Component { ComponentId = 2,  NameComp = "Unit 2" }
};

var course = new Course
{
    Users = users,
    Components = components.OrderBy(c => c.ComponentId).ToList(),
    Evaluation = new List<Evaluation>
    {
        new Evaluation { User = users[0], ComponentId = components[0].ComponentId, Grade = 87 },
        new Evaluation { User = users[0], ComponentId = components[1].ComponentId, Grade = 99 },                   
        new Evaluation { User = users[1], ComponentId = components[0].ComponentId, Grade = 75 }, 
        new Evaluation { User = users[1], ComponentId = components[1].ComponentId, Grade = 65 }
    }
};
```

And following Razor view should do what you need:

```
    @model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Username
        </th>
        @foreach (var x in Model.Components)
        {
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.NameComp)
            </th>
        }
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var userEvaluation in Model.Evaluation.GroupBy(e => e.User))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userEvaluation.Key.UserName)
            </td>
            @foreach (var x in Model.Components)
            { 
                <td>
                    @(userEvaluation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ComponentId == x.ComponentId)?.Grade)
                </td>
                }
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Watch out for this model, it has a lot of circular references, which can be problematic if you're using something like Entity Framework.

Comment: I've done what you said but it gives an error here: @userEvaluation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ComponentId == x.ComponentId).Grade, the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the null check. I switched it above. As long as you're using one of the newer releases of .NET that includes C# 6, it should work.


`@(userEvaluation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ComponentId == x.ComponentId)?.Grade)`